# Coefficient of a falling factorial

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation

Let $a_0,\dots, a_{15} $ be such that $\sum_{i=0}^{15} a_ix^{\underline{i}} = \sum_{i=0}^{15} x^i$. Note that underline means that it's a falling factorial. What is $a_{12}$?

My attempt: obviously we can just compute $x^{\underline{12}}, \dots, x^{\underline{15}}$ and then find $a_{12}$ but that would take a lot of time without a computer. Is there any other way?

Comment: You can start with $$
x^i  = \sum\limits_{k = 0}^i {S(i,k)x^{\underline k } } 
$$ wher $S(i,k)$ denotes the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind#).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's write
$$f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{15} a_k x^{\underline{k}} \qquad \text{and} \qquad g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{15} x^k \text{.} $$
You can recover the $k$-th coefficient $a_k$ of $f(x)$ as
$$ a_k = \frac{1}{k!} \Delta^k f(0) \text{,} $$
where $\Delta p(x) = p(x+1) - p(x)$.
Now note that
$$ \begin{split}
\Delta^{12} f(0) &= \Delta^{12} g(0) \\
&= \sum_{i = 0}^{12} (-1)^i {{12}\choose{i}} \sum_{k=0}^{15} i^k \\
&= 52649939865600
\end{split} $$
And indeed,
$$ 52649939865600 / 12! = 109916 = \sum_{i = 12}^{15} S(15, i) \text{,} $$
which matches with Gary's comment.